# Sharing web front end with other applications

Tags: iis, sharepoint

I'm specking out a set of servers to handle a sharepoint 2007 install and a number of ASP.net applications.  I was wondering if there were any issues running additional websites on a machine or cluster which is running the web front end portion of sharepoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is a problem, as long as you use separate Application Pools for each site. I have seen people run into issues when they have SharePoint and other web apps running in the same pool.

This also depends on how resource intensive your SharePoint site and your web apps are of course.

You can even run different web apps inside your SharePoint IIS site - just put the virtual directory in a different app pool, then setup SharePoint to exclude the path as in this article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828810

Comment: As Matt states, there's nothing inherently wrong with running additional ASP.NET application's on your SharePoint WFEs.  Microsoft's own Commerce Server 2009 platform, for instance, actually places all of its extensions, handlers, and modules in-line with SharePoint in the ASP.NET pipeline.  You simply need to build an awareness of resource utilization, available CPU and memory headroom, and other performance characteristics on your servers.  Establish a performance baseline, place your apps on the WFEs, and then observe changes vs. the baseline to determine if you can live with the result.

Answer (score -1):

Sharepoint is VERY resource hungry, I wouldn't bother running anything else on the same box as the sharepoint admins will complain that these are what is causing the site to run slowly.

Comment: -1 No it completely depends on the resources available to the server environment and how the SharePoint farm is deployed and configured.